# Column Manipulation in Excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007

I have some thousands of row of data in Excel(in single column) but because of some computing error it is showing the data as 
#NAME
#NAME
#NAME
.
.
.
. and so on

When i click any cell the data is shown as **=-GNcVLtPu1QlJ07cMRe4zw**

I need to delete "==-" sign to get the required data as **GNcVLtPu1QlJ07cMRe4zw**

Can any one suggest any method which can convert those thousands line of data into the correct format(doing it manually will kill most of my time)

Thanks

Comment: Find - ReplaceAll should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Pankaj pointed:

1. select the entire column
2. hit **<kbd>CTRL+H</kbd>**
3. put **"=-"** in **`Find`** column and leave the **`Replace`** empty
4. Hit **`Replace All`**

**Reference Snap:**
[image]

That's all you need!

Comment: @user3484748 I'm glad it helped. mark the post as answer if it helped solving the purpose :)